# Azure Active Directory Token URL Path?

Tags: azure, asp.net-web-api, azure-active-directory

I have a Single Page Application that communicates with a Web API that I am attempting to secure using Azure Active Directory. I've done this before using a local SQL database with local accounts and OAuth2 but I've never done it with Azure Active Directory.

I created a new MVC Web API project in Visual Studio 2017 and set the authentication part to "Cloud - Single Organization" and entered the corresponding domain. The API had me sign in during the creation process. The login information I provided was entered into the Web.Config file.

```
<appSettings>
  <add key="ida:Tenant" value="domain.net" />
  <add key="ida:Audience" value="domain.net/WebAPI" />
  <add key="ida:ClientID" value="XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX" />
  <add key="ida:Password" value="XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX" />
 </appSettings>
```

Then in the new Startup.Auth.cs file I have the following:

```
public partial class Startup
{
    // For more information on configuring authentication, please visit https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=301864
    public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        app.UseWindowsAzureActiveDirectoryBearerAuthentication(
            new WindowsAzureActiveDirectoryBearerAuthenticationOptions
            {
                Tenant = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:Tenant"],
                TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters {
                     ValidAudience = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:Audience"]
                },
            });
    }
}
```

I don't see a path that I can call in there to initiate a login. In my original project it was the /Token path which is shown below from my original Startup.Auth.cs file.

```
PublicClientId = "self";
        OAuthOptions = new OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions
        {
            TokenEndpointPath = new PathString("/Token"),
            Provider = new ApplicationOAuthProvider(PublicClientId),
            AuthorizeEndpointPath = new PathString("/api/Account/ExternalLogin"),
            AccessTokenExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromHours(12),
            RefreshTokenProvider = new ApplicationRefreshTokenProvider(),
        };
```

In my original project in order to initiate the login I would use /Token in an Ajax call and pass along the username and password.

```
$.ajax({
    url: url.getURL() + '/token',
    method: 'POST',
    data: {
        username: username,
        password: password,
        grant_type: 'password'
    },
```

How do I initiate the login in the new Web API which is using Azure Active Directory? I don't see a /token path or anything similar in the Startup.Auth.cs file. Is this something I have to add or is the project setup to automatically use the login credentials I entered when the project was first created?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by login, you have a Web API, by definition that's a resource that consumes a Bearer token that you acquire in your Web App (code authorization flow) or SPA (implicit flow). Also, ` <add key="ida:Audience" value="domain.net/WebAPI" />` that should really be the GUID (the Application ID) of your API, otherwise it gets a bit trickier to validate the token.

Comment: I want to use Azure Active Directory to handle logins and assign tokens. So basically the user would open the app, sign in, get a token, and then that token would be used to authorize future use.

Comment: Ok cool, in your SPA use [implicit grant flow to acquire both an id_token and access_token](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-implicit-grant-flow). Samples [here](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/wiki/Samples). Then call your API with the access_token.

Comment: the controller methods that need authentication using azure AD have to decorated with the [Authorize] attribute. It will redirect the client app to the login page.

Comment: @evilSnobu So I need to add OAuth2 data to the API to get it to work with Azure AD?

Comment: @Aravind Yeah, that's what I want to do but I don't know how to perform the login with Azure AD. Once I have the token I'm good to go. It's just getting that token that I'm confused on.

Comment: Since it's a SPA, that logic is all JavaScript. [See this sample](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-javascript-singlepageapp-dotnet-webapi-v2/tree/master).

Comment: @evilSnobu I used the URL in the example you provided. https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant}/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?
client_id=6731de76-14a6-49ae-97bc-6eba6914391e


I replaced the tenant and client_id variables with the correct ones. It gave me back an HTTP 200 when I called that to login but there was no token that I can see.

Comment: The login flow should happen in the browser. Make sure your Web API's manifest has implicit flow turned on in the Azure AD manifest. The id_token returned will come back to you as an URL fragment, NOT response body. For access_tokens, call [this MSAL method](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-javascript-singlepageapp-dotnet-webapi-v2/blob/ad810c3c56f56f5b980e2a93a51b48c4b4117349/TodoSPA/App/Scripts/Ctrls/todoListCtrl.js#L94). Start by looking at App/Scripts/app.js.

Comment: Is it possible to get the id_token back in JSON format?

Comment: @evilSnobu I'm doing something incorrectly. I copied the URL from the AJAX call and put it directly in the browser to see what happens and it's giving me the following message "The reply url specified in the request does not match the reply urls configured for the application"

Comment: Well, add the expected reply URL to the Web API definition in AAD.

Comment: @evilSnobu That worked. I was overthinking it. Thanks for sticking with me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When tying a Web API into Azure Active Directory there is no "/token" URL to call to initiate a login. You have to direct the users to the following website:

http://login.microsoftonline.com/{domain}/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?client_id={client_id}&response_type=id_token&scope=openid&response_mode=fragment&state=12345&nonce=678910

Make sure you enter the actual domain and client_id variables for your app which are listed in Azure. Also, in Azure, make sure the Reply URLs are set. The API will redirect back to your site after the login is complete. This does work for localhost.